# How can I move table row to the top when checkbox is checked and keep same rows checked after refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I:

1. move the table rows which are checked to the top of the table.
2. make sure the same rows which are checked and now at the top of the table stay in the same position even if I refresh the page or go to another page?

This is my JavaScript code:
The first script is to add the rows to the top when the checkbox is checked and the second script is to keep the checkboxes that are checked still checked.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#emp-table :checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var tbody = $('#emp-table tbody')
    
    if (this.checked) {
      tbody.prepend(tr)
    } 
    else {
      tbody.append(tr)
    }
  });
});

jQuery(function Check() {
  if (localStorage.input) {
    var checks = JSON.parse(localStorage.input);
    
    jQuery(':checkbox').prop('checked', function Check(i) {
      return checks[i];
    });
  }
});

jQuery(':checkbox').on('change', function Check() {
  localStorage.input = JSON.stringify(jQuery(':checkbox').map(function() {
    return this.checked;
  }).get());
});
```

Comment: usually a question contains ....a question ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like HTML and CSS in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)